# While Connecting files Network error issue in Eclipse

Tags: html, json, eclipse, networking, cordova

Actually i was trying to have a login page in phonegap using eclipse,so now i have html code in eclipse as well as php code in localhost,I am getting the php code using Json in eclipse.

But after entering `username & password` and pressing login button.Now the issue comes that

**Application Error**

```
 "There was an network error("http://192.x.x.x/learn/co.php?Username="
```

Comment: you should provide more details on what you're doing. What's the code you call when you have this message... I see 192.xxx in the url, are your mobile and your pc running your web server on the same wifi network?

Comment: I am checking through pc using wifi...

Answer (score 0):

Have you add this settings in your config.xml :

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

More info on phone gap doc [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)